# Extract S_VOBSUB encoded Subtitles from .MKV container as .SRT

Tags: extract, subtitles, matroska

I am working in Linux (Ubuntu)
I tried to do it with *ffmpeg* and *mkvtoolnix (mkvextract track)*

**Problems:**
*ffmpeg* does not work with S_VOBSUB encoded subtitles
*mkvtoolnix* converts S_VOBSUB to .idx/.sub ([See Doc](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvextract.html))

I am preparing an auto-extraction shell script, so command line solutions is what I am looking for. Thanks. :)

Comment: You might be able to use the [sub2srt](https://github.com/robelix/sub2srt) script?

Comment: Hi @slhck, thanks. I copied the script file into my local bin... but when I try to convert, it says "Could not detect xxxxx.sub format!" . But in the file properties I can see it is microDVD. (File comes from doing an extraction with mkvextract)

Comment: The problem is that the script works with .sub version 2.0 (most extended) but extractmkv generates another version of .sub I will be looking for another script. [Based on text seen here: http://www.sub2srt.com (Bottom-Right Pharahraph)]

Comment: Ah… FFmpeg should be able to decode MicroDVD subtitles. Too bad VobSub and MicroDVD use the same file suffix, so sub2srt won't work. Do your files come from Handbrake? You could try choosing SSA subtitles instead of VobSub, which FFmpeg should be able to read and encode to SRT (`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -an -vn out.srt`)

Comment: The best way :)